# Как перезапустить таймер python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Цель: Запустить таймер для внутреннего цикла и в случае не успевании завершить внутренний цикл.

```
import threading

crit = False

def Timeout(): 
   crit = True

my_timer = threading.Timer(60.0, Timeout)

while True:
    #code...
    my_timer.start()
    while True:
        if crit == True:
            #code...
            my_timer.cancel()
            break
```

Ошибка:

> threads can only be started once.

Comment: Плохо понятно. Поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня подобной ошибки нет. Один раз выполняется внешний while и потом бесконечно внутренний не заходя в if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) выполняется только один раз, а `cancel()` только отменяет вызов таймера, поэтому попробуйте создавать и запускать таймер на каждой итерации:

```
import threading

crit = False

def on_timeout():
    global crit
    crit = True
    print('on_timeout:', crit)

while True:
    my_timer = threading.Timer(5, on_timeout)
    my_timer.start()

    while True:
        if crit:
            print('Crit!')

            crit = False
            break
```

---

Сделал таймер на основе [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) и теперь он в цикле выполняет вызов указанной функции:

```
import threading

crit = False

class LoopTimer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args if args is not None else []
        self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
        self.finished = threading.Event()

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet."""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.is_set():
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def on_timeout():
    global crit
    crit = True
    print('on_timeout:', crit)

my_timer = LoopTimer(5, on_timeout)
my_timer.start()

while True:
    if crit:
        print('Crit!')

        crit = False
        # my_timer.cancel()
```

А вызов `my_timer.cancel()` завершит выполнение потока